# Build docker image from layers

Tags: docker

I have a big docker image I need to copy to a remote machine.
I build the image on my local machine with an unchanging base image, so only the last few layers change.
I would like to have that base image on the remote machine and only copy the changed top layers to the remote machine whenever they change. I cannot build the image on the remote using its dockerfile because the necessary source files are not present on the remote.

I can separate the image into its layers using [undocker](https://github.com/larsks/undocker), but how do I reassemble the image from its layers on the remote machine?

Comment: why you done push your image to dockerhub then acces to remote server and pull it ?

Comment: If you really don't have a registry available, I wonder if it would work to `docker save` the image, unpack the tarball, `rsync` that to the remote system, rebuild the tarball, and `docker load` the result.  That won't be fast in Docker time, but it would probably save network I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to using a Docker registry, and updating my image with `docker pull`, which I think is the proper way to solve this problem, since it will only download the changed layers.
[This article](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/14/docker-image-size.html) also helped me reduce the size of my images.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with undocker tool so I can't comment on this, but in my understanding image in docker is a "sealed package" ready for distribution in one way or another.

So copying part of the image sounds to me like distributing a part of the package.

I can understand that overhead of big image on the other hand (probably you're looking for faster copying), but it contradicts the docker "ideology" (take image "as is" and work with it)

So, probably the most straightforward option is preparing the sources (those are in the "last few layers") as a distributable package without docker, copying them to the remote machine and then building the image on the remote machine out of a base image and this distributable package

This allows overcoming a workaround of "the necessary source files are not present on the remote" as you say